# Update/rerun a command on every frame?

Tags: mesh, scripting, modifiers

I am doing various particle simulations. There are a number of tools in blender that I would like to apply non-destructively, and have update on every frame. Specifically, remove doubles and face intersect (self). I can take my current mesh and use them, but then my mesh is frozen. It seems that I would need a modifier of these tools to get the effect I want.

How difficult is it to setup a new modifier? What steps are involved? Is there another way to address this issue?

Comment: It seems that you need custom modifiers that manipulate the result from particle system. Here are two tutorials for adding modifiers: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Modifiers/Adding and  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Enjalot/Creating_a_custom_modifier, I also do it myself: http://thebusytypist.github.io/learnblenderdev-site/2015/08/04/how-modifier-system-works-part-3.html. I suggest to ask coding questions on bf-commiters for more detailed answers. Adding a frame update handler in Python may also worth a try. But I do not know if it can access data from modifier stack.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the modifiers are hard-coded and can't be written in as add-ons. Maybe someone else can confirm this?

Comment: @Mentalist Yes modifiers are in C/C++ not in python. Adding a modifier means custom building blender yourself.

Comment: @TheBusyTypist Yep update handlers can access mesh out of modifier stack, they are what I would go for. Depends on vertex-counts of meshes though, they will have poor performance.

Comment: I've updated the question title now that I understand that it's not necessarily a modifier that I need for this. I'm not super worried about performance, especially if this is something I can pre-bake/cache.